# ODBC instant client install issue

Tags: oracle, odbc, instantclient

I am trying to install odbc for instant client 19_14. I have downloaded the necessary .exe files etc and saved them down to my C drive. I have then navigated to the directory:

```
C:\oracle\instantclient_19_14>
```

And I execute the following:

```
 C:\oracle\instantclient_19_14>odbc_install.exe
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
Couldn't find Oracle Instant Client in present directory.
```

Does anyone know why this is. I can see the odbc_install file in the folder, so its not clear why there is an error.

Comment: Which files did you download, and from where? The normal [Oracle distribution](https://www.oracle.com/uk/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html) is ZIP file(s) which you download and unzip - you need a basic package, then can get ODBC package on top. Did you perhaps *only* download and unzip the ODBC package?

Comment: I downloaded the ODBC package (version 19.14), and I also have the instant client basic package (version 21.3). Unless I should try have them on the same version? I didn't think this would be an issue. Maybe I need to set the environment variable for Oracle to the new client folder?

Comment: Having different versions doesn't sound desirable. If your _19_14 folder only contains the ODBC installer then it might just be complaining because it can't find anything else in the same location - where it should be. I think you'll probably need to use the 21.3 ODBC; or if you actually have to use 19.14, you'll need the basic package for that version as well?

Comment: I have both on 19.14 now. However, I'm still getting an error. Do I need to do anything to install client? I'm not sure if just downloading it suffices, but I can't see any install (.exe) files

Comment: You just unzip it, from the c:\oracle directory based on what you've said; the files in the archive should expand into the instantclient_19_14 directory you already have. [Read more about installing ODBC.](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/releasenote-odbc-ic.html)

Comment: Thanks, yeah I've done that but no joy so far

Answer (score 0):

for Oracle client in Windows you need to define System Variable:
OCI_LIB32 -> C:\oracle\instantclient_19_14
and add to Path variable -> C:\oracle\instantclient_19_14

BR,
Ely